# values doesn't appears in autocomplete textbox

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have this `ashx` :

```
string name = context.Request["term"] ?? "";
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
            List<MobilineContact> mbContacts = new List<MobilineContact>();
            MobilineContact mbc = new MobilineContact();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetContactNames", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
                {
                    ParameterName = "@name",
                    Value = name
                });
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    mbc.Id = int.Parse(rdr["Id"].ToString());
                    mbc.Name = rdr["ContactName"].ToString();
                    mbc.Mobile = rdr["ContactNumber"].ToString();
                    mbContacts.Add(mbc);
                }
            }
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(mbContacts));
```

and when I request it here

> http://localhost:43969/ContactsHandler.ashx?term=t

it returns what i expect

> [{"Id":1,"Name":"Test","Mobile":"555555555"}]

and in debug everything is **OK**
in my aspx page I have written this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.toTxt').autocomplete({
     source: 'ContactsHandler.ashx'
   });
});
```

and here's my textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox class="form-control toTxt" ID="To" placeholder="To" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Why my values didn't appears in textbox as autocomplete? I've references jquery, jquery.ui.js and jquery.ui.css. There's no error in console

Comment: Can you include the html that the textbox control renders to?

Comment: Have you tried setting the source to `/ContactsHandler.ashx`?

Comment: I've request it with post and It works.. But I have no idea why

Comment: Make sure your jquery-UI has auto-complete feature selected and also add images folder of jquery-UI to your solution

Answer (score 0):

It's probably to do with `context.Request["term"]` - I'm guessing that comes out as null or something?

You are using a query string parameter to send the value of term, and if I remember correctly, context.Request reads the body - not the query string. Try this instead:

`context.Request.QueryString["term"]` to get the value of term.